# Setting a value in a userform combobox = a variable

Tags: excel, combobox

I'm trying to create a loop that checks the previous weeks selections for duplicates and returns an error if it finds any. My problem is, when I try to take the selected week from the combobox and assign it to the variable 'weekcount', it returns an 'Object Required' error. The following is my code:

```
Private Sub InputButton1_Click()
Dim Weekcount As Long

Set Weekcount = UserForm1.Week.Value

MsgBox Weekcount      

End Sub
```

Comment: Use just `Weekcount = UserForm1.Week.Value` without `Set`

Answer (score 0):

Set is only used when assigning objects (reference type). You are assigning a value type variable and thus it is not required (and not allowed)

Use instead

```
Weekcount = UserForm1.Week.Value
```

and you should be fine.